# Substring value in ssrs to get only month number

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

When I´m running ssrs I have an issue with my field month because value is:

```
[Dim_Tiempo_].[Mes].&[6]
```

So I try to substring to get only value `6`:

```
=CINT(Left(Right(Parameters!DimTiempoMes.Value(0),3),2))
```

But I just get #Error without specifications why. Can someone help me there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you go right and get the last 3 characters, you get [6], then you go left 2, you get [6.. converting this to an int is obviously going to return and error. if you didn't put the CINT..  you would have seen what was happening.. what you need is the following

```
  =cint(replace(left(Split(Parameters!DimTiempoMes.Value(0),"[").GetValue(3),2),"]",""))
```

Comment: that´s true, but if we can remember months can have 2 digits like 10,11 and 12, how can I add validation to check if there are two digits instead one? There is any way to solve that?

Comment: @pepe.. right.. I didn't read the field Name as Month.. see my updated answer

Comment: @pepe it's bit of a hack way of doing it.. but split returns an array with the specified number of sub string.. in the 3rd occurrence of "[" (getvalue(3)) . I get 2 characters to the left of the array.. if it has a "[" then it means there is only one number.. so I replace the [ with nothing.. and then convert what is left to an integer .. hope that makes sense.

Comment: It make sense, I wish that helps to another people who have some trouble like this! Regards